# Выбранный по умолчанию <input type="radio">

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, sql

Есть запрос в таблицу где выводиться цена. Нужно чтобы один пункт был активным. атрибут checked не поможет так как выбирается последний список и при переключении не снимается галочка. Какие есть варианты?

```
<?php
$result_price = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_price WHERE product_id='$id'");
if (mysql_num_rows($result_price) > 0)
{  
$row_price = mysql_fetch_array($result_price);   
do{
echo'           
<li>
<label><input type="radio" name="prod"/> '.$row_price["price"].' руб. / '.$row_price["ves"].' '.$row_price["znach"].'</label>
</li>
';                              
}
while($row_price = mysql_fetch_array($result_price));
}
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может код приложить а не только картинку

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: Следуйте всем инструкциям https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/radio

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, не используйте `mysql_query` и не вставляйте параметры в запрос напрямую — это черевато SQL-инъекциями.

Касательно вопроса: чтобы выбрать нужный элемент действительно стоит использовать `checked`, просто сделайте проверку в теле цикла. Грубо говоря, если индекс элемента равен такому-то, то `checked`